# Logarithm of normal distribution is constant plus Chi squared?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, chi-squared

I'm reading [Bayesian data analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf). On page 85 it is stated that "In the d dimensional normal distribution, the logarithm of the density function is a constant plus a $χ^2_d$ distribution divided by −2." Can someone clarify how to derive this?

For example, let's use $d = 1$. Then the logarithm of the density function of the normal distribution is:
$$
\begin{align}
ln(p(\theta)) &= ln\left({\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\theta-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}}\right) \\
&= ln\left(\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}\right) -{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\theta-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2} \\
&= C -{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\theta-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}
\end{align}
$$
So the above statement would imply that $\left({\frac {\theta-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}$ is a $χ^2_1$ distribution. However, when I look up that distribution I get:
$$
\begin{align}
χ^2_1(\theta) &= {\frac {1}{2^{d/2}\Gamma (d/2)}}\;\theta^{d/2-1}e^{-\theta/2} \\
&= {\frac {1}{2^{1/2}\Gamma (1/2)}}\;\theta^{1/2-1}e^{-\theta/2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;\theta^{-1/2}e^{-\theta/2}
\end{align}
$$
I do not see how these two things are the same. Especially the exponent of theta seems to behave very differently from what is in essence a quadratic formula in theta above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right and the book is wrong, but maybe there is a closely related result that the book misquoted and someone here might recognize what was intended. I would be very curious to hear it in that case, because I can't think of any.

Comment: In your example, if $\theta \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $\left(\frac{\theta-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 \sim \chi^2_1$.  It is not that $\left(\frac{\theta-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2$ *is* a chi-squared *distribution*, but that it *is* a chi-squared *random variable* and it *has* a chi-squared *distribution*